# Cannot show the result of getJson on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a web page where some of the values to show are taken by making a GET on a local url that exposes a JSON file. On the server side, I receive the GET correctly but on the web page it never shows the value retrieved.

```
<div class="count" id="bo"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function getMqtt() {
    $.getJSON('http://192.168.1.159:8080/all',function (result) {
        document.getElementById("bo").innerHTML = result;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do : console.log(document.getElementById("bo").innerHTML);

Comment: Have you checked the network panel in the developer tools to see if a response is coming back and if it contains the information you expect?

Comment: You're likely running into a CORS issue unless your website is also running on `http://192.168.1.159:8080`. Look for errors in your console and network tabs of your developer tools.

Comment: As said by @HereticMonkey , it is a CORS problem. Still, I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to everyone, I didn't see that this was a CORS problem. Then I'm going to open another question in order to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to get the json file via xmlhttprequest:

The URL I used for the json is test.json, change that to the URL where you get the json from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>json retrieval test</title>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
Result: <span id="json_field"></span>
<script>
    function init() {

        let http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        http.open('GET', "test.json", true);

        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/json");

        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById("json_field").innerHTML = http.responseText;
            }
        };
        http.send();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.getElementById("bo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result)`.  If that doesn't work try making it `result.toString()` as it will then render the JSON Object as a string.